# How to change directory using a variable in batch?

Tags: variables, batch-file, cd

I am trying to use a variable to change the current directory in a batch file.
The variable is set as Dan and there is a folder called Dan. It doesn't change though. Here is my code.

```
cd C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\PBot\Profiles
set /p profilename=Enter your profile name:
cd %profilename%
```

Comment: Use `cd /D` to change drive letter AND path.  Type `cd /?` for a longer explanation.

Comment: Your question was well asked, but not well researched.  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+change+directory

Comment: Thanks Wes. But I have already tried that and from what I have read, that cd /d is for changing drives. I might be wrong but it won't work for me.

Comment: It's good practice to put all your path names and path variables in quotes.  Also, you might try the %userprofile% variable.  `cd "%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\PBot\Profiles"` and `cd "%profilename%"`.

Comment: It can change to the Profiles folder, just not the Dan folder.

Comment: Post the ouput/error that you get from this code.  And if this is part of a larger code block, post the whole thing.

Comment: I would like to see you execute all these commands manually from the cmd prompt and show the output.

Comment: I don't get any error. I have it so it echos the current path and then it will dir. It stays in the original path. Here is the code.

Comment: set /p profilename=Enter your profile name:
cd "%profilename%"
echo %cd%
dir
pause

Comment: I did it with cmd the same way and it worked. I am not sure what is going on.

Comment: have you confirmed that the dan folder defiantly exist? does is show an error after you type dan?  Are you running it elevated under a different user that doesn't have that folder?

Comment: I have manually created the Dan folder. I even made sure it worked in the command prompt. It will work in the cmd prompt just not in a batch file. It is very strange.